# Specific line in .htaccess causing 403 instead of directory listing

Tags: apache-httpd

In a Wordpress installation, a .htaccess file is causing a 403 error when accessing to a sub directory `foo` (the sub directory is not part of the Wordpress installation but is created by myself later). For example, I have the following tree file:

```
/www
 |-wp-content/
 |-[all the stuff for wordpress]
 |-.htaccess
 |-foo/
   |-.htaccess
```

More specifically, the line in `www/.htaccess` causing the error is the following:

```
RedirectMatch 403 \.(cgi|asp|aspx|cfg|dll|exe|jsp|mdb|sql|ini|rar)$
```

To overcome this, I've created `www/foo/.htaccess` with:

```
RedirectMatch 200 \.(cgi|asp|aspx|cfg|dll|exe|jsp|mdb|sql|ini|rar)$
```

But I don't understand why the line impacts the directory listing of `foo`. The name of the sub dir is really `foo` (for the tests) and the direcory is empty apart the `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there's a file matching the regex in your foo directory.

`\.(cgi|asp|aspx|cfg|dll|exe|jsp|mdb|sql|ini|rar)$` will match anything ending by a `.` and followed by one the extensions listed.

So if you have `bar.cgi` in your foo directory, the path will be `foo/bar.cgi` and the end of the path does trigger the match and prevent the listing of the directory.

[Showcase](https://regex101.com/r/opQTYZ/1) of this behavior on regex101

Comment: There isn't anything in `foo/`, only the `.htaccess`without which it doesn't work.

Comment: Then in this case, are you sure your apache install allow directory listing ? (If there's nothing in the diretory, the RedirectMatch in the .htaccess is not the reason you get a 403)

Comment: Yes, because adding `www/foo/.htaccess` with the line given in my question make the directory listing working.

Comment: Hum I'd be curious of what the behavior is if you set an empty .htaccess in foo (or any other file like `test.txt` for example, without the redirectmatch you have actually)